Determine whether the following statement about prime factors of $2^n+1$ is true or false:
There are infinitely many prime numbers $p$,$\enspace$s.t.$\enspace p$ doesn't divide $2^n+1$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_+.$
My view is that the set $\lbrace 2^n+1\vert n\in\mathbb{N}_+\rbrace$ doesn't cover enough prime number, leaving only finite primes uncovered. I'm thinking about proving it by using binary representation of $2^n+1$, i.e. $1000...001$, but I'm not making any progress. Could anyone give me any hint on this method? Or if you have other ways to solve the problem? Let me know plz!

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Do you know of a single prime with this property (except $2$)? Perhaps the proof of this property can be of guidance to you for the more general case.

The answer is yes, the set such primes is infinite.
In fact, let $A=\lbrace p\mid p\text{ divides }2^n+1\text{ for some }n\rbrace$, and let $B = \Bbb{P}\setminus A$, i.e. all the primes not in $A$. Your statement can the be formulated as; B is infinite. But even more is true: in fact, it has positive density in the primes. Hasse proved in the $60$'s that $\delta(A)=\frac{17}{24}$, implying $\delta(B)=\frac{7}{24}$. See https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0166 p. $19-23$ for his original proof (in German). See also https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-118/issue-2/The-set-of-primes-dividing-the-Lucas-numbers-has-density/pjm/1102706452.full for an English version (proof of Theorem A).
As a sidenote, $p\mid 2^n+1$ is clearly equivalent to $2^n\equiv -1$ mod $p$, and for this to have a solution is equivalent to $2$ having even order in $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^\times$. Thus, to count $B$, we need only count the primes $p$ such that $2$ has odd multiplicative order modulo $p$. This makes it easy to find examples of $p$ satisfying the property: for example, $2$ has order $3$ modulo $7$, so $7\in B$.
This equivalence above is also the starting point of Hasse's proof. With some clever manipulation, he transforms it to a statement about splitting of primes in certain number rings, which allows the application of theorems from algebraic number theory. It is only $~4$ pages, so if you are comfortable with algebraic number theory, it is definitely worth a look.

Thanks! It's a much more generalized answer, and it's very interesting to see that $a^n+1$ can amazingly cover so many prime numbers.
